# How to integrate Kdenlive into the Ubuntu Desktop design?

Tags: kdenlive

The [Kdenlive website](https://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu) says to install Kdenlive for Ubuntu as follows:

> We encourage every *Ubuntu users (*Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04) to use our official PPAs.
>   The last stable Kdenlive version (16.04.x) is currently available
>   here: ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-testing

However, installing Kdenlive this way, does not provide a proper design integration.

Things I noticed:

- Double menu
- Wrong theme

How can I properly integrate Kdenlive into the default Ubuntu desktop?

[image]

Comment: I can't say for this exact kde program but on others I use, there is a setting in the preferences, something like `use system theme` or use `GTK3 theme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kdenlive (like all KDE apps) is built on Qt.

## Global menu

Installing the `appmenu-qt` and `appmenu-qt5` packages should fix it.

## Theme

Qt 4 offered a configuration tool (Ubuntu package: `qt4-qtconfig`) but the Qt developers removed it for Qt 5.

In addition, Qt 4 seemed to accurately detect what desktop environment it was on and pick style accordingly, but Qt 5 seems not to do it. This is, apparently fixed in Qt 5.5.1. In fact, Qt 5 apps correctly set style to GTK+ on 16.04 Xfce (Qt 5.5.1, no Qt5Ct).

Instead, you will have to use a third-party configuration tool, [Qt5Ct](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=168066).

You would have had to build Qt5Ct from source, but the WebUpd8 PPA packaged it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt5ct
```

[image: Qt5Ct screenshot]

As in the picture,

- Set the *Style* to *GTK+*.
- In the *Icon Theme* tab, select the icon theme you use.
- Set the font (in the *Fonts* tab). Ubuntu Unity defaults are *General*: *Ubuntu* and *Fixed width*: *Ubuntu Mono*

Edit `~/.profile` and add

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
```

To tell Qt apps to use Qt5Ct's configuration.

If that doesn't work, add

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"
```

to the `/etc/environment` file.

Install the `kde-runtime` and `libqt5libqgtk2` packages.

Logout and login again. Kdenlive should be integrated into Unity.

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the default font-size, 11?

Comment: 10, I think. But I don't run Unity, so maybe it's different.

Comment: It's 11. Any ideas how I can improve the appearance of [buttons](http://i.imgur.com/2RTHrin.png)?

Comment: That should be handled by the Style = GTK+ step.

Comment: I had to install `kde-runtime` and `libqt5libqgtk2` to get the buttons!

Comment: @orschiro I'll add that.